# Plot swiped domain when varying parameters

Tags: plotting, regions

I would like to plot the region swiped by varying some parameters, and I've been unable to find a function that does what I want. ParametricPlot works when the region depends on two parameters, but there is a priori  no reason it could not depend on more.

To be clearer, let us we have a set of 2D points parametrized by three continuous variables, $t$, $s$ and $u$ :

```
(x(t,s,u),y(t,s,u))=(t^2+u,s)
```

Now assume I restrict the range of $t$, $s$ and $u$, say $0<t<1$ ,$0<s<1$ and $0<u<1$. I would like to plot the locus L of points :

```
L = [(t^2+u,s), {0<t<1, 0<s<1, 0<u<1}]
```

How could I do that? Bear in mind that the above is an example, but I would like to be able to do this for generic $x(t,s,u)$ and $y(t,s,u)$.

Trying out

```
ParametricPlot[{t^2+u,s},{t,0,1},{u,0,1},{s,0,1}]
```

Does not work, as it has too many parameters. Looking at the docs, it seems that it assumes that the parametric region must have only two parameters.

Comment: Have a look at `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Oops, my bad, for some reason I thought it was only for curves. I will amend the question to ask for regions with more than 2 parameters. That is why I ran into the problem initially actually.

Comment: "there is a priori no reason it could not depend on more". Well, there is no reason why a function cannot depend on many arguments, but a parameterization should only have as many parameters as required by its dimension. So, with 3 parameters, we would expect this to be a 3D "surface", and so it would need to be embedded in a space with at least 3 dimensions. If we're working in three dimensions, then all we would have done is define a solid region in that space.

Comment: In your specific example, we can do a change of variables to get: `ParametricPlot[{w, s}, {w, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 1}]`, which is just a "solid" 2D region in 2D space. So, I think there is some disconnect. Either this example doesn't clearly describe your actual intent (in which case more info and context is needed), or you're misunderstanding what the ParametricPlot function is used for.

Comment: For the first comment. An efficient parameterizatin should have only 2 arguments for a 2D region, sure, but there is absolutely no reason it has to. You are assuming I am trying to draw a specific 2D surface and choosing a convoluted parametrisation, but this comes out naturally in my problem, and there is no simple way at all of simplifying it, as the dependencies are quite complicated.

For the second comment, of course I can simplify this simple example. But generally, there is no way to do so. Hence my "bear in mind" section in the question.

Comment: Then maybe create a table of points and use ListPlot

Comment: That might work, but I think it takes a lot more work than that. Indeed if you want your points to fill your region correctly, the sampling should depend on the region. I.e. if I have a "e^s" in there, I should sample s logarithmically rather than linearly to have nice filling. This could be done for example with a metropolis algorithm, but precisely what I was looking for is if there is some way to do this already in mathematica. The exercise is exactly the same as the 2-param surface, so it's very strange that there isn't any way to do it similarly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136896/discussion-between-frotaur-and-lericr).

Comment: If I understand the edit history right, I suggest asking a new question (about the multiple parameters) instead of moving the goal posts. (You could roll back this question to the appropriate edit and reference it in a new, if you like.)

Comment: I can do that, but I don't really see the point. The title still fits perfectly, and I moved that goalpost only once when I went from only two parameters to three, this was my bad. The other edits are not "moving goalposts" : the solutions tried to solve only the given example, without giving thought to possible generalisations (even simple ones). I guess that was my bad too for the too easy example, but that is why I added another one.

Comment: So, as I said I moved the goalposts only once, when going from 2 to 3 parameters. There were no answers then, so no harm done. Then people answered, by solving only the provided example (which btw can be done by hand in 2 seconds, and then plotting the region with pencil and paper). In the original question, it was explicitely stated that I would like to do this for general x(t,s,u) and y(t,s,u), which both provided answers didn't work for. I provided more context to actually guide the answers to an actual answer, and the post was closed. So really, I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = {t, u, s} |-> {ArcSinh[Sin[t E^s u]] + 3 Log[s], 
    EllipticK[Min[s t Cos[u], 0.9 Sin[s^2]]]};
(*  f = {t, u, s} |-> {t^2 + u, s};  *)
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[2], 
  Flatten[Table[
    Point[f[t, s, u]], {t, 0.01, 1, .01}, {s, 0.01, 1, .01}, {u, 0.01,
      1, .01}], 1], Axes -> True}]
Show[Table[
  ParametricPlot[f[t, u, s], {t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}], {s, 0, 1, .01}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good way, but does it rely on the fact that the Region is "simple", i.e. expressible easily with some analytic functions ? If I replace $t^2+u$ with something more complicated like $Sin[t s u] + 3 Log[s]$ will it still work ? I tried on my machine but it just evaluated indefinitely (meaning >3 minutes)

Comment: I'm going to give an upvote to this answer, as it may be the way possible as things stands, but I would like to point out this is still not the best solution. This is because (as mentioned in my "repost" of the question) the sampling is not adaptive, just linear. This result in the artifacting that we see on the left of the plot, where we would need a higher density of point, relative to the right part, where linear spacing is ok. As far as I know, in the two parameter case, the "parametricPlot" function, automatically yields adaptive sampling.

Comment: To see this sampling problem, simply use the second implementation, but sample over t instead of s, and let s be handled by ParametricPlot. This gives a much smoother plot without the artifacting. And this is precisely because ParametricPlot does intelligent sampling. So this solution is acceptable, but very far from ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion):

```
DiscretizeRegion[
    ParametricRegion[{t^2 + u, s}, {{t, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}}],
    MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .01}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Another seemingly nice solution, but it seems to run in the same problem as soon as we choose a region which is slightly non-trivial. Could this be adapted ? I provided another less trivial example in the question.